# Scala : Collect with generics

Tags: scala, generics, partialfunction

Given the following scenario

```
val items = List("a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3, false, true)
def intItems = items.collect {case i : Int => i}
def stringItems = items.collect {case s : String => s}
```

is there a way to create a generic function to handle this behavior?

I tried the following

```
def itemsAs[T]: List[T] = items.collect { case item: T => item }
```

but

```
itemsAs[Int]
```

returns

```
List[Int]] = List(a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, false, true)
```

Another approach is to provide the `partial function` as argument, but still have to duplicate the `case i: Int => i` and `case s: String => s`. Is there a way to make it more compact? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val items = List("a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3, false, true)
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
def collect[T: ClassTag] = items.collect { case x: T => x }
collect[Int] // List(1, 2, 3)
collect[String] // List(a, b, c)
```

See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html for more details.

Comment: This is the approach I followed, but added the following `def itemsAs[T <: MyInterface](implicit tag: ClassTag[T]):` in order to have it typed and dont allow every param to be provided